# Quick directions to/from home or starred place in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have two places starred in new Google Maps -- home and work. But, I have quite problems using them, when requesting directions or when searching for them in `Start` or `To` fields for directions:

1. When I search for any address and a pin appears on maps, I can see something like "14 minutes from home -- drive" for approximately half of my searches and for rest of them I don't see that label and must zoom out map largely to find my star and click it.
2. When I type in `Start` or `To` fields and start typing `Home` or `Work` I can't never find these starred places in suggestion list. I always must write nearly entire address to get, what I'm looking for.
3. In addition, I can type my home or work address hundreds of time and new Google Maps does not seem to remember it or even notice, that I'm searching for it quite most of the time. I must always type nearly entire address to have it appear on suggestion list. I'm pretty sure, that in "old" Google Maps I only needed to type it few times and Google started to "remember" these addresses and each next time I only needed to type 3-4 characters to get this address on top of suggestions list.

Either I'm missing something or using starred places in new Google Maps is extremely useless, not comfortable and frustrating. Is there any way I can access my starred places quickly? So adding them as start point or destination of any directions or route would take only 2-3 seconds and not 10-15 seconds each time, as currently?

Comment: Do you just have them "starred" like you can do with any location, or do you have them defined under the special "places"? (If you type "home" in the search box, are you offered an "EDIT" link?) Are you using the latest version of Google Maps? Are you in the U.S.?

Comment: @AlE. I have them both starred and somehow, someday I added them as "home" and "work" (or else, how would GM know, what is my home and work, to display "13 minutes from home" under pins?). This is an old case, I don't quite remember details, but I think, they're added in mobile GM, though I'm nearly not using it. When I'm typing "home" or "work" in GM search box I see neither these addresses, nor edit link. I'm talking about website / browser version of GM (not: mobile) and thus it always is the newest version. I'm outsite USA (Poland), but I'm using Google Maps in English (if that matters).